# time .sleep() taking place at incorrect order in commands; always at the beginning of the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

The code below is a stripped down version (for clarity reasons) of a small application I am working on; an application for spelling words for children.

#### The problem

The problem I am having is in the function `flash_correct()`; its purpose is to show a word for 5 seconds, then hide again.

I must have a silly blind spot, but no matter where I put the `time.sleep(5)`, the function starts with the break of 5 seconds, while the entry: `self.entry2` never shows up:

[image]

Without the `time.sleep(5)` however, it shows up correctly:

[image]

Where is my blind spot?

#### The (stripped down) code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango, Gdk
import subprocess
import time

       
class InterFace(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Woorden raden")
        maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(maingrid)
        maingrid.set_border_width(10)

        self.entry2 = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry2.set_size_request(500,60)
        self.entry2.set_child_visible(False)
        self.entry2.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 30'))
        maingrid.attach(self.entry2, 0, 4, 4, 1)

        quitbutton = Gtk.Button("Stop", use_underline=True)
        quitbutton.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 20'))
        quitbutton.connect("clicked", self.on_close_clicked)
        maingrid.attach(quitbutton, 3, 7, 1, 1)

        showword_button = Gtk.Button("↺", use_underline=True)
        showword_button.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 25'))
        showword_button.connect("clicked", self.flash_correct)
        showword_button.set_size_request(60,20)
        maingrid.attach(showword_button, 0, 6, 1, 1)

    def flash_correct(self, button):
        # the time.sleep(5) seems to take place at the beginning
        # no matter in which order I set the commands
        self.entry2.set_text("Monkey")
        self.entry2.set_child_visible(True)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.entry2.set_child_visible(False)

    def on_close_clicked(self, button):
        Gtk.main_quit()


window = InterFace()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.set_default_size(330, 330)
window.set_resizable(False)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: If gtk is anything like Tkinter, then the GUI doesn't actually update until after the function ends and control returns to the main message processing loop. So if you change an attribute, sleep, and change the attribute back, all in one function, then it won't have any observable effect other than making your window unresponsive for a while.

Comment: @Kevin That sounds logically, I'll try!

Comment: @Kevin I split the function `flash_correct()` in two sub- functions, called by a new function, the `time.sleep()` in a separate one, but the result is the same I am afraid. The thought made sense though, and it must be something like that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Nec136HN I have not used gtk but that code should be close to what you want, using a thread or a timeout are other options http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TimeoutsIOAndIdleFunctions.html

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Brilliant, thanks *a lot* Could you post it so I can accept?

Comment: @JacobVlijm, no worries, I will throw an answer together in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use time.time to hide for roughly 5 seconds calling `Gtk.main_iteration()` in the loop to avoid your app becoming unresponsive.

```
def hide(self, time_lapse):
    start = time.time()
    end = start + time_lapse
    while end > time.time():
        Gtk.main_iteration()

def flash_correct(self, button):
    # the time.sleep(5) seems to take place at the beginning
    # no matter in which order I set the commands
    self.entry2.set_text("Monkey")
    self.entry2.set_child_visible(True)
    self.hide(5)
    self.entry2.set_child_visible(False)
```

There is a good explanation in the pygtk faq 7. [How can I force updates to the application windows during a long callback or other internal operation?](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=edit&file=faq03.007.htp)

> If you have a long-running callback or internal operation that tries to modify the application windows incrementally during its execution, you will notice that this doesn't happen; the windows of your app freeze for the duration.
>
> This is by design: all gtk events (including window refreshing and updates) are handled in the mainloop, and while your application or callback code is running the mainloop can't handle window update events. Therefore nothing will happen in the application windows.
>
> The trick here is to realize where your operation can take a while to return, or where it is dynamically changing the window contents, and add a code fragment like this wherever you want an update forced out:

```
while gtk.events_pending():
   gtk.main_iteration(False)
```

> This tells gtk to process any window events that have been left pending. If your handler has a long loop, for instance, inserting this snippet as part of the loop will avoid it hanging the window till the callback has finished.
>
> More eloquently, in the words of the great Malcolm Tredinnick, 'this requires using what should be called "Secret Technique #1 For Making Your Application Look Responsive"(tm):

Adding `while gtk.events_pending():` may be no harm also.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a timer that integrates with the main loop, rather than busy-waiting until the time has elapsed. Luckily there is just such a facility in GLib:

```
def flash_correct(self, button):
    self.entry2.set_text("Monkey")
    self.entry2.set_child_visible(True)
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(5, self.flash_end)

def flash_end(self):
    self.entry2.set_child_visible(False)
    return GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE
```